# feof, doesn't seem to work - text files

Tags: c

I'm reading lines from a text file using `fgets();`

I have a loop with: `while(!feof(fp))`

The thing is, the program keeps entering the loop even after I've reached and read the last line, and in debug the file ptr shows only dots and not a string of data.

How can I get it to know I've reached the end and not enter the loop again?

```
        while (!feof(fp)) {
            if (strcmp(data2->ID ,data1->ID)<0) {

                fseek(fp, backTo, SEEK_SET);
                fprintf( fp, "%s",lin2);
                fprintf( fp, "%s",lin1);

                flag = 1;
            } 
            else 
            {
                strcpy(data1->ID,data2->ID);
                strcpy(data1->name,data2->name);
                data1->price=data2->price;

            }

            if(fgets(line2, sizeof(line2),fp)!=NULL)
            {
                itemSize2=strlen(line2)+1;
                strcpy(data2->ID,strtok (line2,","));
            }

        }
```

There are only 2 lines in the text file, I'm using fseek and going to the begining of the file then I use fprintf twice and write on those lines, after that I should reach the EOF

Comment: Simplify your code, see if feof still misbehaving. For starters, fset may reset the eof flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean it enters the loop once?

`feof(fp)` returns true if the program has attempted to read beyond the end of file, not when it's read up to it.  The system doesn't necessarily know if there's more of a file (it may be dynamically generated, `stdin` being the canonical example), but does know if it hit an end of file.

You need to test `feof(fp)` after each `fgets(fp)`, or test to see how many characters were returned by `fgets(fp)`, or do a one-character `get` and `unget`.

Comment: it keep entering the loop and doesn't know when it reaches the end of file

Comment: @Nadav:  Could you be more exact?  Does it enter the `while` loop body once after reading the last input, or more than once, in the same run?

Comment: there's a fseek call that takes the file ptr 2 lines up, there are only 2 lines in the files, i write over them using fprintf, after i write over them  i use fgets and then i should rach the eof, but it keeps going in the while loop forever

Comment: I think you misunderstand how files work. They're based on bytes, not lines, so if you overwrite the last 2 lines with something shorter, there will still be the end of the old file contents left behind. Also, it's impossible in C to switch between reading and writing on `FILE` without an intervening seek. Attempting to do so results in undefined behavior, which you may be seeing.

Answer (score -1):

Well I use this custom function....

```
BOOL    CheckFileEnd(FILE *fp)
{
    BOOL res;
    long currentOffset = ftell(fp);

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

    if(currentOffset >= ftell(fp))
        res = TRUE;
    else
        res = FALSE;

    fseek(fp, currentOffset, SEEK_SET);

    return res;
}
```